# homotopy quotient categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory

(Trying to rephrase an earlier question)

In topology, a continuous map $f: X \to Y$ has a ``homotopy cofiber" $Cf$ included in a cofiber sequence
$$
X \to Y \to Cf \to \Sigma X \to \Sigma Y \to \Sigma CF \to \ldots
$$
when $f$ is a cofibration, the cofiber is homotopy equivalent to $X/Y$.

Now, if $Y$ is a category, say, of modules over a ring $R$, and $f$ a functor from another category (e.g. embedding of projective modules into all modules), is there a similar cofiber category and a cofiber sequence?

Comment: Perhaps I've answered your question in 1970, in a paper on shape theory (Fund.Math. -- or was it published in 1971?). Your question is not quite clear to me, thus I might be wrong.

Comment: What is supposed to be the suspension of a category ?

Comment: One could think of a category as a simplicial set with special properties, and borrow constructions from simplicial topological sets but I don't know if this can be worked out. Thus the question.